# Counting overlapping days in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, python-datetime

In my django project, I store user's vacation:

```
class VacationRequest(BaseModel):
    requested_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='vacation', verbose_name='User')
    start = models.DateField(__('Start'))
    end = models.DateField(__('End'))
```

I need a feature to generate report. Reports are generated for selected range of days:

```
class Report(BaseModel):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='reports')
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, verbose_name=__('Department'), related_name='reports', null=True, blank=True)

    title = models.CharField(verbose_name=__('Title'), null=True, blank=False, max_length=32)

    start = models.DateField(__('Start'))
    end = models.DateField(__('End'))

    csv = models.FileField(__('CSV'), null=True, blank=True, upload_to=report_upload_path, max_length=256,
                           storage=reports_storage)
    xls = models.FileField(__('XLS'), null=True, blank=True, upload_to=report_upload_path, max_length=256,
                           storage=reports_storage)
    pdf = models.FileField(__('PDF'), null=True, blank=True, upload_to=report_upload_path, max_length=256,
                           storage=reports_storage)

    def generate_files(self):
        headers = ['First name', 'Last name', 'Department', 'vacation days']
        department_kwarg = {'userdata__department': self.department} if self.department else {}

        vacation_filter = models.Q(vacation__status=2, vacation__start__gte=self.start, vacation__end__lte=self.end) # what should I change here?

        users = User.objects.filter(company=self.company, **department_kwarg).annotate(
            days_used=models.Sum(models.Case(models.When(
                vacation_filter, then=models.F('vacation__archive_net_days')
            ), output_field=models.IntegerField(), default=0))
        ).annotate(
            days_left=models.F('userdata__vacations_days_in_year') - models.F('userdata__used_vacations_days')
        ).values_list('first_name', 'last_name', 'userdata__department__title', 'days_used', 'days_left')

        self._generate_csv(users, headers)
        self._generate_pdf(users, headers)
        self._generate_xls(users, headers)
```

it works almost fine, however, I want to calculate overlaping days also.
For example, when user's vacation is between *10 July* and *20 July* and in my report I set `start` date to *11 July* it will return 0 days but it should calculate days between.

This is because

```
vacation_filter = models.Q(vacation__status=2, vacation__start__gte=self.start, vacation__end__lte=self.end)
```

-- it uses vacation__start__gte - which is not correct, I am not sure what should I use here

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It's confusing. If vacation is btw july 10~20, you have to filter with one specific date, not start/end isn't it?

Comment: If a report from 15 to 20, should vacation from 10 to 17 be included?

Comment: Then we should calculate only days from 15 to 17